# Trim or replace PowerShell string variable

Tags: regex, powershell, sharepoint, office365, trim

I have a string variable that holds the following information

> **@{EmailAddress=test1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com},@{EmailAddress=test2@tenant.onmicrosoft.com}**

I am using this variable for a cmdlet that only accepts data in the format of

> **test1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com, test2@tenant.onmicrosoft.com**

I have tried `TrimStart("@{EmailAddress=")` but this only removes `@{EmailAddress=` for the first user and I guess `TrimEnd` would not be much use as I presume that it is due to the fact it reading the string as one line and not as user1,user2 etc.

Would anyone be able to provide advice on how to remove these unwanted characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution would be to use the `-replace` function. This is just a one-liner:

```
'@{EmailAddress=test1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com},@{EmailAddress=test2@tenant.onmicrosoft.com}' -replace '@{EmailAddress=([^}]+)}.*?', '$1'
```

**Regex used to replace:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin, the diagram helped me understand - much appreciated

Comment: Hi Martin, Sorry to move the goalposts a bit here but is there an option to add double quotes to each of the users for example "test1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com", "test2@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" - I appreciate this may be an entirely different question requiring a different response but thought I would ask here first. Thanks

Comment: Sure, just replace `'$1'` with `'"$1"'`

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution is to use Regex to extract the strings that you want, and combine them into a result:

```
$str = "@{EmailAddress=test1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com},@{EmailAddress=test2@tenant.onmicrosoft.com}"
$pattern = [regex]'@{EmailAddress=(.+?)}'
$result = ($pattern.Matches($str) | % {$_.groups[1].value}) -join ','
```

$result then is:

```
test1@tenant.onmicrosoft.com,test2@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
```